# como le hago para importar una tabla csv a postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv

Intento importar una tabla `csv` de `excel` a `postgresql` pero dio logro, los pasos que he intentado son:

1. Estoy en Mac
2. Abro pgadmin
3. Me voy a la tabla donde quiero alojarla
4. Selecciono el archivo en donde la voy a poner
5. Abro la lista desplegable con el botón control
6. Elijo impot/export
7. Dentro de la ventana emergente
8. import/export: Elijo import
9. Filename: Pego la ruta de mi archivo que está alojado en mi Mac.

   Format: csv
   Encoding: He seleccionado utf8: **nada**, lo dejo en blanco: **nada**
   OID: la he dejado en NO, y también en SI, y me devuelve error.
   Header: también he intentado SI y NO y nada. Quote: por default dejo "
   Escape: por default dejo ': yme devuelve succesfully job created sin embargo si le pido los details me dice copy = 0

En que estoy fallando ?

De antemano una disculpa por no expresarme como se debe, creo que lo mejor sera exponer todo el caso y tal vez me ofrezcan una mejor solución a lo que estoy intentando, mi necesidad es hacer una pagina con estadísticas de Formula1, la estoy haciendo a través de Django, las bases de datos las proporciona ergast.com, solo que me gustaría tener las bases de datos en mi propiedad con el motivo de no depender de terceros, ya tengo las DB  en mi poder en formato csv, son alrededor de once tablas de exel, al ser bases de datos ocupan espacio en mi equipo, decidí tenerlas en postgres o bien en sqlite3 solo que en ningún caso puedo copiarlas, tengo entendido que con django es muy fácil utilizar sqlite3 porque viene integrada, así que cambie el gestor por sqlite pero aquí no logro cargar el DB, en sqlite me solicita en formato sql, y no de donde obtenerlo, y en postgres realice otro intento, y me dice succesfully, sin embargo le doy a details y me aparece 0 imports y se me borra la base de datos De la Fuente

Un error que me sale es:
--command " "\copy public.f1app_laptime (id, lap, "position", "time", milliseconds, driver_id_id, race_id_id) FROM '/Users/alejandromendez/Desktop/Programando/Python/django/ProyectosDjango/FormulaUno/f1project/f1db_csv/lap_times.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER QUOTE '"' ESCAPE '''';""

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "1"
CONTEXT:  COPY f1app_laptime, line 2, column time: "1"

Comment: y que error te da??

Comment: y si te sale o no un error que has investigado??

Comment: y cual es el contenido del CSV y cual es la estructuda TDD de la base de datos?

Comment: creo que para poder ayudarte necesitamos mas informacion... colocar una guia de lo que hiciste si bien es importante no es suficiente ..